# Defining a combinatorial problem for a given equation

Tags: combinatorics

I was given the following task: define a combinatorial problem to the following equation, and say how each side of the equation solves the given problem.
The equation is:
$$ n\binom{n}{r} -r\binom{n}{r}=(r+1)\binom{n}{r+1} $$
I tried to think of a problem that both sides solve, but couldn't think of any... I don't want the answer but some kind of a hint to the combinatorial problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If it helps, I usually think about these types of thing like selecting a set of people from a group and then giving some of them "special titles."  Also, if it helps, notice that $n=\binom{n}{1}$.  For example, if I had $\binom{n}{1}\binom{n}{r}$ I might say I'm going to select $r$ people to form a committee (from $n$ candidates), then select a president of the committee from the original $n$.  The president may or may not already be in the committee, so your final committee might have $r$ or $r+1$ people in it.

EDIT: Use thinking along the lines of what I said before, but re-write the LHS of that equation as $\binom{n}{r}(n-r)=\binom{n}{r}\binom{n-r}{1}$.  Think about the committee selection, and choosing a president.  How big is the committee you form (with the president)? and, do you choose the president first? or the "regular" committee members first?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

> From a set of $n$ elements, choose one of them, and then choose $r$ more.

(The first selected objetc must be somehow different form the others).